# Django settings.py not being detected

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to Django and I'm having some difficulty getting my settings.py to load properly. I'm getting the following error:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /admin
>
> Put 'django.contrib.admin' in your INSTALLED_APPS setting in order to
>      use the admin application.

However, my settings.py INSTALLED_APPS looks as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'squaredcrm' )
```

Looking through the error log, I've noticed its not picking up any of my changes to installed apps:

> Django Version: 1.4.3 Python Version: 2.7.3 Installed Applications: ('django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.sites', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles') Installed
>   Middleware: ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

I cannot figure this out for the life of me. Any other changes seem to be working, but this field will not update. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's a silly question, but did you restart your server after making the changes?

By default, production (by which I mean Apache-based, and perhaps other) instances of Django do *not* auto-reload on changes. The Django development server *will* auto-reload, as long as you don't specifically tell it not to.

You have to restart (or stop and then start) an Apache-based Django for it to see the file changes.

Important tip: do *not* run a production site off of the development server. It is slow, slow, slow, and probably insecure in ways I don't know about.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I did not even think to restart Apache. This has solved my problem. Thank you all for your help, and happy holidays.

Comment: I'm not sure that having done several face-plants on this particular problem qualifies as "genius" -- maybe more like "slow learner." :-)

Answer (score 2):

If other changes are picked up, this is probably because `INSTALLED_APPS` is being redefined somewhere in your `settings.py` file.

This could be:

- At a subsequent line.
- In an import (likely a `from x import *`).

Comment: Hello and thank you for the quick reply. I appreciate the help. Sadly, there are no imports in the settings.py file as is there nowhere else that installed_apps is being redefined in that file.

Comment: Edit: I stand corrected, this is still an issue. I apologize.

Comment: To configure Admin in your application look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/)

Comment: Hi, that is the guide I followed to configure the admin setup. I'm stuck because it is not loading.

Comment: This was it for me! Rewriting my ALLOWED_HOSTS at the beginning of the file, without realizing it was already defined half a page down. Thanks four years later :-)