# App name not registering when running server in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to make a simple rest API with Django and am having trouble whenever I am running the server.

I get the error that my leads module does not exist and I created that app with the

*python manage.py startapp leads*

and the installed Apps section in my settings.py file look like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'leads.apps.LeadsConfig', # I also tried `leads` and that doesnt work as well
    'rest_framework'
]
```

my project directory looks like this

```
manager
  leads 
   migrations
   __init__.py
   admin.py
   api.py
   apps.py
   models.py
   serializer.py
   tests.py
   urls.py
   views.py
  manager
   __init__.py
   asgi.py
   settings.py
   urls.py
   wsgi.py
  manage.py
Pipfile
Pipfile.lock
```

As you can see I have the **init**.py file and that is empty and I do not know why my leads app is not a module that can be used?

someone please help.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try restart your server after making the changes. You have to restart Django for it to see the file changes.

You can also try the solutions proposed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964113/django-settings-py-not-being-detected?rq=1), which is the same as you, maybe you forgot something.